# NSURLSession uploadTaskWithRequest with mime type?

Tags: swift, mime-types, nsurlsession

I'm trying to upload an image to a cloud storage with NSURLSession.

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageAttachment, 1)
NSURLSession.sharedSession().uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data)
```

The image has been successfully uploaded, but it seems that the server does not recognize the data as an image. When I checked the content type from the cloud storage's console, it is set as `application/octet-stream`.

My question: how to specify mime type for file uploaded with NSURLSession?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it.

I need to set the `Content-type` header with `NSMutableURLRequest` before passing it in to `uploadTaskWithRequest`.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

request.HTTPMethod = Method.PUT.rawValue
request.setValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")

let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageAttachment, 1)
NSURLSession.sharedSession().uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data)
```